# Access violation whenever accessing a singleton object in the procedure library

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

We are using a .pl to compress all our .r code running on a specific appserver. We have now found some issues accessing a few of these programs inside the library.

We seem to notice that only singleton objects have these issues.

Currently we can do a workaround by removing the files from the .pl and putting them in a directory before the .pl.

We are using Progress Version 11.6.3.

These are examples of classes we have found having issues with.

```
USING Progress.Lang.*.

ROUTINE-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

CLASS GROUP.prg.rep.Singleton: 
DEFINE PRIVATE STATIC VARIABLE Instance AS Singleton NO-UNDO.

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Purpose   : basic private constructor                                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
CONSTRUCTOR PRIVATE Singleton ():
END CONSTRUCTOR.    

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Purpose   : get the instance of the class                                                         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
METHOD PUBLIC STATIC Singleton GetInstance ():
    IF NOT VALID-OBJECT (Instance) THEN 
      Instance = NEW Singleton().
    RETURN Instance. 
END METHOD.

END CLASS.
```

I have removed some vital information from this class as I cannot share company code but this principle is the same between all our issues.

```
=====================================================
PROGRESS stack trace as of Fri Mar 22 13:53:36 2019
=====================================================

Progress OpenEdge Release 11.6 build 1442 SP04 on WINNT 

Startup parameters:
-pf E:\Progress\OpenEdge\116\startup.pf,-cpinternal ISO8859-1,-cpstream 
ISO8859-1,-cpcoll Basic,-cpcase Basic,-d dmy,-numsep 46,-numdec 44,(end 
.pf),-b,-pf E:\OpenEdge\WRK\116\MENU_PF\MENUD.pf,-h 10, -d dmy,-L 1000,-inp 
32000,-E,-lng 2,-s 15000,-TB 31,-TM 32,-Bt 15000,-mmax 10000,-l 12500,-tok 
4000,-T E:\TMP,-yd,-yx,-D 10000,-reusableObjects 10000,(end .pf),-basekey 
INI,-ininame E:\OpenEdge\WRK\116\Menu_PF\ICE.ini,-p IndexationStartup.p,- 
param 0005#1292#1#22/03/2019 13:53:24,260+01:00

Exception code: C0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION
Fault address:  00007FF60600E74D 01:000000000048D74D 
E:\Progress\OpenEdge\116\bin\_progres.exe

Registers:
RAX:0000000000000001
RBX:0000000020B75C00
RCX:0000000000000000
RDX:000000002155C240
RSI:0000000000000523
RDI:00007FF6066FE180
R8 :0000000000000104
R9 :0000000000000443
R10:000000000600E000
R11:00007FF605B80000
R12:0000000000000080
R13:00000000003E9000
R14:0000002000001000
R15:0000000001000000
CS:RIP:0033:00007FF60600E74D
SS:RSP:002B:000000000051E730  RBP:0000000000000001
DS:002B  ES:002B  FS:0053  GS:002B
Flags:00010202

Call Stack:
Address           Frame
00007FF60600E74D  000000000051E770  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+74E6D
00007FF606039A19  000000000051E7A0  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+A0139
00007FF605FF22D6  000000000051E7D0  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+589F6
00007FF605FC9C9B  000000000051E860  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+303BB
00007FF605FCA4D3  000000000051EA70  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+30BF3
00007FF605FCABAE  000000000051EAD0  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+312CE
00007FF605BDDFC0  000000000051EB60  common_srvrLogFile+4C840
00007FF605BE0E85  000000000051EC20  common_srvrLogFile+4F705
00007FF605FC54FC  000000000051ECA0  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+2BC1C
00007FF605FC6CF4  000000000051ED00  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+2D414
00007FF605FC6E08  000000000051ED60  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+2D528
00007FF605BFAA56  000000000051EE20  common_srvrLogFile+692D6
00007FF605FE6FA5  000000000051EF20  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+4D6C5
00007FF60600A959  000000000051EFD0  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+71079
00007FF606014B7A  000000000051F000  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+7B29A
00007FF605FC71FE  000000000051F030  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+2D91E
00007FF605FC91EB  000000000051F0C0  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+2F90B
00007FF605FCA28A  000000000051F2F0  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+309AA
00007FF605FCA507  000000000051F500  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+30C27
00007FF605FCAA96  000000000051F560  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+311B6
00007FF605BCD418  000000000051F700  common_srvrLogFile+3BC98
00007FF605BFAA56  000000000051F7C0  common_srvrLogFile+692D6
00007FF605FE81BA  000000000051FA40  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+4E8DA
00007FF605FE9F9E  000000000051FAA0  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+506BE
00007FF60600A959  000000000051FB50  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+71079
00007FF606014B7A  000000000051FB80  Progress::ClrBridge::ITypeManager::operator=+7B29A
00007FF605C1F74F  000000000051FBB0  dbut_utclex+1F5BF
00007FF605BAB5E8  000000000051FDC0  common_srvrLogFile+19E68
00007FF605C3E8F3  000000000051FDF0  dbut_utclex+3E763
00007FF6063A7ABE  000000000051FE20  Progress::ClrBridge::rnProFromClr::FindOnPropath+13530E
00007FFF5D2B13D2  000000000051FE50  BaseThreadInitThunk+22
00007FFF5F9654F4  000000000051FEA0  RtlUserThreadStart+34
```

Comment: What is the nature of the "issues"?  Are you experiencing unexpected behavior? 
Or maybe there are error messages?  Do you have a reproduce-able example that you can share?

Comment: The class name does not match the constructor name. That's usually a compile error

Comment: That's my mistake, I changed the class name to remove confidential information, but it indeed compiles. Ill add a protrace file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have opened a progress case and came to the conclusion we we're using the -Yd parameter in the .pf file. This causes some dirty errors using singleton objects. Progress are still looking on how to solve this issue but our workaround is just removing the -yd parameter.

Hope this can help some people.

Answer (score 0):

I you can't find anything in the Progress Knowledge Base about this (I didn't) you should probably open a case with Progress Support, assuming you are under maintenance.

You could also try a newer Progress version or at least a newer service pack for 11.6, 11.6.4 seems to be available.